# Loop Excel columns

Tags: ruby, capybara

The solution below solves my problem when there is a vertical column that validates the record in the cell with the field on the application screen.

But if the spreadsheet is horizontal, I cannot read the records and validate them on the application screen.

```
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab.xls', "r")
sheet = book.worksheet 4
xls_offset = 1
row_offset = 2
sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
  expected_tooltip = row[1]
  break if row[1].nil?
  expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
end
```

**OK: I get the values ​​from the status column [invisible....etc]**

| fields | status |
| --- | --- |
| Leitura | Invisível |
| Hidrometro | Invisíve |
| Diametro | Invisível |
| Lacre | Obrigatório |

**NOK**

| code | situation | tab | leitura | hidrometro | diametro | lacre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | ok | B | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |
| 9 | ok | C | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |
| 10 | ok | C | Invisivel | Invisivel | Habilitado | Invisivel |

How to adjust the code above to do this reading horizontally to read the records [Invisivel, Invisivel,Habilitado,Invisivel] in line 3 from the Leitura column?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting a specific row and then iterating over cells in this row skipping the first N cells:

```
row = sheet.row(2) # get the third row
row.each_with_index do |cell, index|
  next if index < 3 # skip first three cells
  # do something with the data specified in cell variable
end
```

Comment: sorry but that do not work.. I need to change this code to read My excel spreadsheet read column values ​​horizontally. Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
    book = Spreadsheet.open('c:/temp/gab.xls', "r")
    sheet = book.worksheet 4
    xls_offset = 1
    row_offset = 2
    sheet.each_with_index(xls_offset) do |row, idx|
     expected_tooltip = row[1]
    break if row[1].nil?
     expect(page).to have_css("tr.tvRow:nth-child(#{row_offset+idx}) .tvCell:nth-child(6) img[tooltip='#{expected_tooltip}']")
    end
  end